# How to write something to .txt log file from .aspx page (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, logging, asp.net

This code does not seem to compile, I just need to write something to a small log text file (a new row to end of file).

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e ){

    FileSystem myFileSystem = new FileSystem();
    myFileSystem.WriteAllText(logFile, hash, false);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any class called FileSystem in [the `System.IO` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx). Is this something new in .NET 4.0 which you're trying to use?

Note that the [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) class has a *static* method called [`WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx). Is that what you meant?

EDIT: To append to a file instead, use [`File.AppendAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but WriteAllText does not seem to append to end of log file

Answer (score 2):

FileSystem is a class from the VisualBasic namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.aspx

Have a look at the FileStream class in C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx

Answer (score 2):

FileSystem is in Microsoft.VisualBasic.File.IO.  You'd have to reference that.

Although you probably don't really want FileSystem at all.  You probably want System.IO.File

Answer (score 1):

Without a doubt log4net! http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This one seem to compile:

```
File myFileSystem = new File();
myFileSystem.AppendAllText(logFile, hash, false);
```

Comment: It shouldn't - File is a static class, and AppendAllText is a static method.